# Copy cells from a certain column based on a criteria into another Column from the next available row

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets, "Signed" and "April". 
I want to copy Column "Y" from "Signed" based on certain criteria into column "A" starting from the next available/blank row. ( so right under the existing data).

My criteria for column Y is that if column L = month of cell "D2" from "April" AND the year of cell "D2" from "ApriL"...( so right now D2 is 4/30/2017)..
then copy that cell in the next row of Col A of "April" and keep adding on.

my code is as follows:

```
Dim sourceSht As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
Dim DestRow As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MonthVal As String

Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R[-1]C)"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
MonthVal = ActiveCell.Value

Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Signed")
Set myrange = sourceSht.Range("Y1", Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set ws2 = Sheets("April")
DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each rw In myrange.Rows
  If rw.Cells(12).Value = MonthVal Then
    myrange.Value.Copy Destinations:=Sheets(ws2).Range("A" & DestRow)
  End If  
Next rw
```

Comment: What is rw? And Cells(12).Value? so it is a fixed value? like  Cells([Lines],[Rows])  is it Line 12? or you wanted Row 'L'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim sourceSht As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
Dim DestRow As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MonthVal As String
Dim rw As Range

Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R[-1]C)"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
MonthVal = ActiveCell.Value

Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Signed")
Set myrange = sourceSht.Range("Y1:Y" & sourceSht.UsedRange.Row - 1 + sourceSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
Set ws2 = Sheets("April")
DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' + 1

For Each rw In myrange '.Rows
    If sourceSht.Cells(rw.Row, 12).Value = MonthVal Then
        DestRow = DestRow + 1
        rw.Copy Destination:=Sheets("April").Range("A" & DestRow)
    End If
Next rw
```

Edit: fixed a potential loophole at line 15 (from `Set myrange = sourceSht.Range("Y1:y" & sourceSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count)` to `Set myrange = sourceSht.Range("Y1:Y" & sourceSht.UsedRange.Row - 1 + sourceSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count)`), in case there are unused rows at the top.